# partialview not properly rendered with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with using PartialViews and Ajax.I want a search based on selection of a category and to render the result list in partialview.

The problem is when I click on the search button it renders the same page in the targetDiv instead of the PartialView it's supposed to load.

Here is my code

```
@model IPagedList<MvcApplication1.Models.Tender>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="search-section" class="container">

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "get",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "search_result"

        }))
        {
            <div class="grid4 a-left first">
                <label for="regularInput">Search Tenders:</label>
            </div>

            <div class="searchtext a-right">
               @Html.DropDownList("SearchCatagory", (SelectList)ViewBag.DropDownValues)
               @Html.TextBox("SearchBox", "Type your search key here.")           
               <button type="submit">GO</button>
            </div>


        }
</div>
@Html.Partial("_SideViewLeft")
@Html.Partial("_SearchResult", Model)
```

Comment: show partial view complete code

Answer (score 0):

In your partial view add this line at the top of it, because your partial is rendering as a normal view with it's master layout:

```
@{

Layout = null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not suppose to load the partialView..Can only be used to update a target element in the html. So you have to call an action in the controller which will fetch the search results return with the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify your controller code or partial view, so this is a little guesswork.
You need to return your partial page as the result of the controller action that is receiving the form posting.

As you have specified:

```
Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
```

It will post back to the *same page* it is on, not another partial view. That will return a full page and insert it into the specified `#search_result` element.

There are a couple of solutions to this.

### 1) Post to a specific action instead

```
Ajax.BeginForm("SearchAction", new AjaxOptions
```

Your `searchAction` method in the controller can then check the post is valid and return a `searchAction` PartialView.

### 2) Detect whether the request is coming from Ajax

You can then return a full page, or a partial page, depending on use.

```
   if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
        ViewBag.Layout = null
   }
   else
   {
        ViewBag.Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml";
   }
   return View();
```

Just make sure your page contains:

```
   @{
        Layout = ViewBag.Layout;
   }
```

Then it can conditionally render as a partial or full view.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following

1. Make sure the view you are returning is a partial view.
2. Make sure you are returning a partialview result from you controller.

Partial views do not have a layout section. you dont need to set it to null. just don't have it there!